# Diamond with Questionmark in fonts

Tags: php, wordpress, unicode, fonts, character-encoding

In my website I use the language Malayalam. Everything works fine except the excerpts. In the front page the website only shows like <10 words for each products. So most of the time at the end of the excerpt there is a black diamond with a question mark.

[image: See the image]

Now when I open the product listing page f or the same(with the same content, the question mark is not there.See this:
[image]

So can some one please explain me why it comes like this and come up with possibly a solution?

PS: The website is in wordpress!

Comment: good to see Malayalam font, don't know whether this resolves your problem https://wordpress.org/support/topic/special-characters-converted-to-question-marks-on-save

Comment: Tried everything from there, still no luck! :(

Comment: This is most probably not a font problem but a character data error. Please provide a testable case (HTML and CSS) that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: This is the site: http://www.maplebooks.in/ on which I am trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else have this problem, I guess this could help:

The issue was, the theme creators used substr function to remove the extra characters from the excerpt. So this function was removing the characters which are obsolete when stand alone in this language and the browsers are not finding a way to represent these. So it comes up with the question marks in the diamonds. So I removed the substr function and limited the excerpt with lesser number of words to achieve the same functionality without breaking the layout of the theme.

And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

i think your wordpress malayalam font are not supported to your css please define your HTML character - encoding to set your language in your site.

Generally **?** is one type of character which are not supported to your language that means if we define copy right symbol as it is in our site at that time it will display **?** character but on that we use **&copy** at that time it will displayed right character .

Comment: This is the site: http://www.maplebooks.in/ on which I am trying! The language is malayalam. So in your opinion what should I try?

Comment: i checked your site i think when you enter description in your admin panel at that time there is something special character entered like **'** or **""** which are not supported 

please enter single quote in keyboard may be it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand. The editing page doesn't have any characters like this.

Comment: If you trust on me Can you give me your admin credential i will change and manage it.